# Сохранение данных между запуском приложения в Android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.
Ситуация такая, есть приложение которое показывает погоду по координатам или вручную введенному местоположению человека. Так как не хочется каждый раз обращаться к google geocoder'у за названием города и координатами, хочется что бы они куда то сохранялись между запусками приложения. А обновлялись только при изменении названия города в настройках, либо при изменении координат через location listener. Сохранить нужно 1 string и 2 double, так что бд делать как мне кажеться нецелесообразно, так же как и файл заводить. Как это сделать что бы было максимально правильно? Может в SharedPreferences засунуть?

Comment: SharedPreferences - это та же база данных.

Записывайте в базу и не бойтесь. Завтра нужно будет ещё пару параметров записать и что? в случае с базой все будет достаточно просто.

Comment: Просто опыта пока мало и поэтому спрашиваю как сделать правильнее, что бы ресурсов ело меньше.

Comment: это уже преждевременная оптимизация будет. Вот если бы решили MySQL притащить на андроид, что бы все это сохранить...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Может в SharedPreferences засунуть"
именно. ну вы же сами предложили идеальное решение! 
SharedPreferences  как раз для того, что бы сохранять настройки, и служит

Comment: Ну тогда другой вопрос. В какие методы прописывать сохранение и извлечение? Пока думаю над onPause и onCreate соответственно.

Comment: используйте "парные методы". Например OnStart|OnStop. или читайте значения только тогда, когда они понадобятся, а записывайте только тогда, когда изменятся.

Comment: для SharedPreferences нет метода putDouble.((

Comment: Разобрался, сделал toString()